# Setting CRS on QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3

I am just learning how to use QGIS (3.4.1) and am having some issues overlaying some data (CSV file) with a QuickMapServices base map. I feel like this is an issue with the CRS, but am not 100% sure.

I have set the base map from QuickMapServices outlined below:

[image]
Outlined in the bottom right pane, this is set to ESPG: 3857, however, the coordinate (-11315, 6710551) is way out of place when I hover over London UK etc.

I have then added my own data, outlined below:

[image]

Which is also in ESPG: 3857, but the coordinates seem to be the wrong way around?  I.e. the point -0.37, 51.36, should be 51.36, -0.37. But then even if it was it still wouldn't be lined up correctly with my base map.

I am pretty confident in my wich is formatted as below, but I'm just at a bit of a loss as I seem to have changed the projections for both layers to ESPG: 3857?

[image]

Comment: the points are in 4326 not 3857

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EPSG : 3857 is a projected CRS with meters as unit so the coordinate (-11315, 6710551) are right for London area.

On the other hand your CSV seem to use degree as unit so it's not in 3857, you could try to use WGS84 (EPSG : 4326) if you dont know witch CRS it use

Comment: Yes that worked, thank you!